# Make AppBar transparent and show background image which is set to whole screen

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-appbar

I have added **AppBar** in my flutter application. My screen already have a background image, where i don't want to set appBar color or don't want set separate background image to appBar.

I want show same screen background image to appBar also.

I already tried by setting appBar color as transparent but it shows color like gray.

**Example code:**

```
appBar: new AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
//        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0077ED),
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: new Text(
            "DASHBOARD",
            style: const TextStyle(
                color:  const Color(0xffffffff),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                fontFamily: "Roboto",
                fontStyle:  FontStyle.normal,
                fontSize: 19.0
            )),
      )
```

[image]

Comment: Grey color because of elevation. You can set `AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, elevation: 0.0,)` and appbar will be transparent

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky Tnx but its not showing background image which i set to whole screen. it show white color layer

Comment: Dunno if you are still stuck but I found a workaround in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17088.

Comment by RyanAfrish7
Remove the appBar from the appBar slot of the Scaffold. Add the appBar into a Stack within the Scaffold's body. Add another Container to fill the screen to the Stack. Add all the components into that Container. That's it. You may now add background blur to the appBar and it works like a charm. Worked for me

Comment: Body extending behind AppBar is now supported by Scaffold. Please see my answer for transparent AppBar with body extending under it.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

you can use Stack widget to do so. Follow below example.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text(
                "Hello World",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0.0,
            ),
            body: new Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Aegletes Thank you for let me know. now it is working perfectly.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work as intended, honestly I'm not sure what changed?

Comment: Sorry it was my fault with the backgrounds apparently, thank you for your solution.

Comment: Set Scaffold `extendBodyBehindAppBar` to `true`.

Comment: This uses a nested scaffold, which isn't a good practice, @gswierczynski's answer should now be considered the correct one.

Comment: Set elevation to 0 is really helpful.

Answer (score 293):

This is supported by Scaffold now (in stable - v1.12.13+hotfix.5).

- Set Scaffold `extendBodyBehindAppBar` to true,
- Set AppBar `elevation` to 0 to get rid of shadow,
- Set AppBar `backgroundColor` transparency as needed.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      appBar: AppBar(
//        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        backgroundColor: Color(0x44000000),
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text("Title"),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text("Content")),
    );
  }
```

Comment: if you are wondering why this doesn't work for a ListView in the body this is because of the default padding of the ListView. You can adjust that by setting the padding `ListView(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),`

Comment: Also it might not work if ```SafeArea``` is applied, remove ```SafeArea``` .

Comment: now the appbar items are floating all over the screen..(In ListView)

Comment: If you don't want to change the elevation, you can also set `shadowColor: Colors.transparent` so it is completly transparent.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this behavior with a SliverAppBar?

Answer (score 82):

You can use Scaffold's property "**extendBodyBehindAppBar**: ***true***"
Don't forget to wrap child with SafeArea

```
  @Override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          widget.title,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/background/home.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            child: Center(child: Text('Test')),
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

None of these seem to work for me, mine went something like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
    elevation: 0.0,
  ),
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(
                'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517030330234-94c4fb948ebc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1275&q=80'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 100, 0, 0),
          child:
          // Column of widgets here...
        ),
       ),
     ],
   ),
 );
```

Comment: I think there is no need for the "brightness: Brightness.dark,"

Answer (score 13):

**Output:**

[image]

A lot of answers but nobody explains why `extendBodyBehindAppBar` works?
It works because when we assigned `extendBodyBehindAppBar` as true, then the body of the widget takes the height of `AppBar`, and we see an image covering the `AppBar` area.

**Simple Example:**

```
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: Container(
        // height: size.height * 0.3,
        child: Image.asset(
          'shopping_assets/images/Fruits/pineapple.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          height: size.height * 0.4,
          width: size.width,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 12):

There could be many cases, for example, do you want to keep the `AppBar` or not, whether or not you want to make the status bar visible, for that, you can wrap `Scaffold.body` in `SafeArea` and if you want `AppBar` to not have any shadow (unlike the red I provided in example 2), you can set its color to `Colors.transparent`:

- ##### Full image (without `AppBar`)

  [image]

  ```dart
  Scaffold(
    extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
    body: SizedBox.expand(
      child: Image.network(
        'https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/3770388.jpg',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  )
  ```
- ##### Full image (with `AppBar`)

  [image]

  ```dart
  Scaffold(
    extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      shadowColor: Colors.red,
      title: Text('MyApp'),
    ),
    body: SizedBox.expand(
      child: Image.network(
        'https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/3770388.jpg',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  )
  ```

Comment: in example 2, add `elevation: 0,` to the AppBar

Answer (score 6):

```
Scaffold(extendBodyBehindAppBar: true);
```

Answer (score 5):

that's what I did and it's working

This is supported by Scaffold now (in stable - v1.12.13+hotfix.5).

Set Scaffold extendBodyBehindAppBar to true,
Set AppBar elevation to 0 to get rid of shadow,
Set AppBar backgroundColor transparency as needed.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

In my case I did it as follows:

Additional create an app bar with a custom back button (in this case with a `FloatingActionButton`). You can still add widgets inside the `Stack`.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EditProfilePageState createState() => _EditProfilePageState();
}

class _HomeState extends State< Home > {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          this._backgroundImage(), // --> Background Image
          Positioned( // --> App Bar
            child: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0.0,
              leading: Padding( // --> Custom Back Button
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  mini: true,
                  onPressed: this._onBackPressed,
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // ------ Other Widgets ------
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _backgroundImage() {
    return Container(
      height: 272.0,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: FadeInImage(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        image: NetworkImage(
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1527555197883-98e27ca0c1ea?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80'),
        placeholder: AssetImage('assetName'),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onBackPressed() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}
```

In the following link you can find more information [Link](https://mrflutter.com/fullscreen-page-with-transparent-appbar-in-flutter/)

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to set foregroundColor attribite to the desired color in order to make the navigation  icon and the title visible

Note that the foregroundColor default value is white.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this This code work for me

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _buildContext = context;
    sw = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    sh = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return new Container(
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(image: backgroundImage),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text(Strings.page_register),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0.0,
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: new Form(
                key: _formKey,
                autovalidate: _autoValidate,
                child: FormUI(),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

backgroundImage

```
DecorationImage backgroundImage = new DecorationImage(
  image: new ExactAssetImage('assets/images/welcome_background.png'),
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use stack

- set background image

  - Another Scaffold()

    - set background color transperant
    - set custom appbar
    - use column with singleChildScrollView or ListView

[image]

```
@override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              backgroundBGContainer(),
              Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                appBar: appBarWidgetCustomTitle(context: context, titleParam: ""),
                body: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _spaceWdgt(),
                      Center(
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Image.asset(
                              "assets/images/user_icon.png",
                              width: 117,
                              height: 97,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),




  Widget backgroundBGContainer() {
      return Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage("assets/images/ground_bg_image.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            color: MyColor().groundBackColor),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the answers, but either it only works on iOS, or they make against scaffold recommendations within scaffold (visit [Multiple Scaffolds for each page inside a Flutter App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60561552/multiple-scaffolds-for-each-page-inside-a-flutter-app)).

The solution is to use SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setBrightnessWithoutAppBar(context, AppColors.transparent, Brightness.light); //look this
     return Scaffold(
       extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
       body: Stack(children: [
         Positioned(
           top: 0,
           child: Container(
             width: MedSize.widthPhysical,
             height: MedSize.heightPhysical * 0.7.byUI(true),
             decoration: const BoxDecoration(
               image: DecorationImage(
                 image: AssetImage('assets/images/jesus/lovesYou.jpg'),
                 fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
               )
```

And in some new file you make your method available:

```
SystemUiOverlayStyle setBrightnessWithoutAppBar(BuildContext context, Color backgroundColor, Brightness brightness) {
  SystemUiOverlayStyle style = SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: backgroundColor,
    statusBarIconBrightness: brightness,
    statusBarBrightness: brightness,
  );
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(style);
  return style;
}
```

It seems to me that until Flutter version 3.12, using the AppBar on Android, even with height 0, overlaps the body, even with the use of `forceMaterialTransparency = true` -regarding the use of image, of course.

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/206345)