# make appbar the same color of the body

Tags: flutter, background-color, appbar

I need to use the property of `AppBar`, but I need the app bar to be the same color as the body. As if there is no appbar. I used the same color to the body and appBar but the appBar have a darker color!

**Material App code:**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'AppName',
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Color(pagesBackgroundColor),
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          color: Color(pagesBackgroundColor),
        ),
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**Home Page Code:**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(pagesBackgroundColor),
        title: Text(
          "What's up!",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Column(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just remove the appBar? Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53080186/make-appbar-transparent-and-show-background-image-which-is-set-to-whole-screen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set appbar color to transparent and 0 elevation:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: Text(
          "What's up!",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Column(),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing the `appBar` completely and use the Align widget to place your other widget on top of the page like it was the `appBar`.

If you do remove the `appBar`, make sure to place your Scaffold inside a `SafeArea` widget.

I hope this helps until someone else can show how to make the `appBar` background color invisible.

```dart
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    body: ListView(
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: TextButton(),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

set extendBodyBehindAppBar to true and set the background color of  AppBar() transparent. Here is an example:

```
Scaffold(
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
```